# GIS Information for Netherlands

Tags: data, weather, netherlands, railroad

I am currently interested in any kind of GIS Information about Netherlands. I need it for some kind of research. Such informations as temperature, soil composition, precipitation, elevation are very interesting for me.

Also, I would be interested in any kind of railway infrastrukture data, such as traffic intensity, noise, track age and so on.

My question is, if there are any of the mentioned data available and how to export them to (for example) Excel. Until now I have been working with ESRI ArcGIS product family (ESRI ArcGIS for Silverlight API and ESRI ArcGIS .NET SDK). So if you mentioned some service, please give me some advice how to use it (of course if you know how).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As it stands your question is far too broad for our focussed Q&A format so we will need you to narrow its scope to a single focussed question before it can be re-opened.  Previous Q&As here on The Netherlands may be worth reviewing: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands